# How to run cucumber test with JUnit in Eclipse

Tags: cucumber

When I try to run my cucumber test from eclips (mars) as a JUnit they just stops in the middle.

They work if I run them from maven.

Please see screen shot at:
https://snag.gy/oz5Pjv.jpg

If you got any ideas please let me know.

Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be two problems.

1) From my test I executed code from within my app that called System.exit. Then I got a:
The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
The solution for this was just not to test that part.
2) But the test did not get on to the next scenario, the reason for that was that I did not know that I could clean up before next scenario took place. I fixed this by adding a:
    @After
    public void after() throws Throwable
    {
        exitApplicationSupport.cleanUp();
    }

..and in cleanUp() i called:

frameFixture.cleanUp();

Perhaps this helps someone else.

Best regards
Fredrik